# MVC .net Core2 - Model is null at controller (when using Jquery ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using asp.net core2 and jquery ajax

I am using Jquery ajax to post to a controller. However at the controller action all values are null

However when I try to post it via ajax to the server, the values appear as null
What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code

UPDATE: 
THERE IS NO CONTROLLER ACTION FOR NOW, I am just checking to see if the model does not return null

the Jquery function is called from the update button class as thus

```
  $('.Update_Class').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(e);



function ehi(e) {

var fd = new FormData($("#Basket")[0]);
alert('Courtnery');

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/Shopping_Basket/Shops_AddToBasket_Update",//"/Shops/AddToBasket", //
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function (message) {
```

and the View Page

```
public class Shops_Basket
{
    [Key]
    public int BasketID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Dates { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price_Unit { get; set; }

    public decimal Total { get; set; }



    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public Products products { get; set; }

    public decimal Basket_Total
    {
        get { return Quantity * Price_Unit; }
       // set { Basket_Total = Basket_Total; }
    }
    public decimal Invoice
    {
        get { return Quantity * Price_Unit; }
        // set { Basket_Total = Basket_Total; }
    }
```

and finally the view page

```
 <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dates)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price_Unit)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsCompleted)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dates) 
            <img src="/images/Department_Categories/@(item.ProductID).png" alt="@(item.products.Product_Name)" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail_50 rounded" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="col-2 form-control75 col-md-5" type="number" autocomplete="off" style="width:20px;" min="1" size="5" max="10000" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.ProductID" class="ProductID" />
            <input class="Update_Class" id="Update" type="submit" value="Update" name="Submit" />
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price_Unit)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsCompleted)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.products.ProductID)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BasketID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.BasketID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BasketID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What does the controller action look like?

Comment: where are you calling the `ehi` JavaScript method ?

Comment: What is the element with `id="Basket"`? And you cannot generate form controls for a collection using ` `foreach` loop (its generating `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model). Refer [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). And we do not even know what your POST method is!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not using ADO.NET rather MVC Datacontext, also the post method is via ajax jquery and not a controller action, hence the e.preventdefault

Comment: @Shyju and cal5barton updates made to your questions above

Comment: Did you even read the link?  And using ADO.Net has nothing whatsoever to do with it,  nor does `e.preventdefault `, and saying _the post method is via ajax jquery and not a controller action_ makes no sense - the ajax call makes a post to your `Shops_AddToBasket_Update` controller method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I removed the formdata part (which sends the entire form) and just sent it as a Json type and here is the final code

```
type: "POST",
    url: "/shops/test",   
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
success: function (message) {
```